# dataframe.all() returning True when condition not met

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have a dataframe:

[image]

I only want rows with values less than 6 for example.

I enter:

```
dists_df.all(axis=1) < 6
```

and I get True for every row.

I would think everything visible in the dataframe screenshot should return False.

Thank you.

Comment: The condition isn't in the all function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your order of operations backwards. `dists_df.all(axis=1)` returns `True` for all rows first because each row exists completely. You then essentially run `True < 6` which is true, as in this case `True = 1`. You have to reverse the order.

```py
(dists_df < 6).all(axis=1)
```

Comment: So computers use logic.  That should help me in the future.  Thank you!